# Swift UITableView scroll jumps when appending cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView` which contains a message thread conversation. I'm trying to allow the user to scroll up to view previous messages, and seamlessly load previous messages. I'm able to append the previous messages just fine, but the `UITableView` jumps when I append the messages. How can I append messages without the table view jumping. Here is the code I have when I append the messages:

```
// Create the index paths for the updated messages
let indexPaths = (0..<newMessages.count).map { NSIndexPath(forItem: $0, inSection: 0) }
// Append new items
self.messageThreadTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
```

The `newMessages` array contains the messages to be appended to the `UITableView`, which were appended correctly to the `UITableView's` data source array. Is there another method to append to a table view which won't make the scrolling jump?

Comment: have you tried saving scrollOffset before the insert and set after the insert ?

Comment: I have tried that. There is still a jump effect that occurs. I want something similar to iMessage where you can scroll up through the messages and the table view loads previous messages without any jumping.

Comment: can you post a video ?

Comment: I'm not able to post one on Stack Overflow

Comment: you can post somewhere else and share a link